# How do I avoid the Dragon while taking King Foltest along with me in the Prologue of The Witcher 2?

Tags: the-witcher-2

In the prologue, just after the first meet with the Dragon, there's a section where Geralt is supposed to (drag?) King Foltest across the walls.

How do I avoid getting maimed by the dragon? The first pass is easy, the second pass (just after the dragon breathes fire) is were I'm getting stuck at.

The tutorial mentioned hitting some button, but I'm getting frustrated by this

Comment: May or may not be related [to this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22537/how-do-i-not-get-incinerated-or-cut-down-on-the-very-first-battle)?

Comment: I had a look at that, that's not quite the same - that question deals with the first time you meet the dragon - mine's the second @GraceNote

Comment: Useful to know, then. I'll keep the question linked, though.

Comment: @GraceNote sure thing :)

Comment: That stupid dragon.  I died at this part too, because the camera changed right at the beginning and I wound up running immediately into the dragon's open blazing furnace of a mouth and dying instantaneously.

Comment: @StrixVaria tell me about it, I did the same :\

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure that you keep running down. Don't let go of that key.

The game is prompting you to press the right mouse button to dodge into cover from the dragon's fire. You'll notice the icon appear near the bottom of the screen; press it as soon as you can so you don't die, then continue running.

Comment: yep, that's what I ended up going. Also might want to mention the point about turning off "Difficult QTEs" under Gameplay settings

Answer (score 0):

Choose the easy level, keep your finger on the S button (as the camera is the wrong way), and there is a key to keep your mouse moving backwards too, for some reason this helps you go faster.